# Use React fetch to call Dango REST getting a 403 response

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch

I am hosting a React app (http://localhost:3000/) and want to authenticate a User from a Django REST app (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) using a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) call. I'm using `django-cors-headers` to address the CORS issue but still get a `403 Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api-auth/login/` error/

My User is a direct subclass of `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and I am using `rest_framework.urls` [LoginView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/urls.py#L19) to log the user in. If I call this from the builtin Django template (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/) I can successfully log in but when I POST from the React app using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) I get a 403 error.

I use [django-core-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) for the CORS challenge but it doesn't seem like it's sending the Cookies back with the response.

I've tried POSTing to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/ using Postman which also receives a 403 error.

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

A portion of settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',

    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
]
```

I am calling the API using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
handleLogin (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.body)
        return response
      })
    }
```

The User can be correctly authenticated while calling the DRF from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ so I am confident the DRF-app is working as expected. Can someone help me address the connection between the React app and DRF?

Comment: You have enable csrf, it's posibble that endpoint call needs the CSRF token.

Using the middelware: django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: @josemlp Is that not supplied with the `'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')` section of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react app have to request the csrftoken from the server, using the suitable  endpoint and store this cookie.

For example:

```
# Django view.py
def get_csrf(request):
    return HttpResponse("{0}".format(csrf.get_token(request)), content_type="text/plain")

# Django urls.py
url(r'^api/get_csrf/?$', get_csrf, name="get_csrf"),
```

JS Code:

```
$.get( "api/get_csrf/", function(data) {
  Cookies.set('csrftoken', data);
});
```